# Movie about last days of WW2 where students are killed

Tags: identify-this-movie

Things I remember: Some German students get caught while distributing some papers in which they criticize Hitler's war. They get interrogated by the police, and I think tortured, and in the end of the movie they are decapitated.

In the movie it is suggested that the allies are very close, so this seems to happen at the end of the WW2.

Does anyone know what's the name of the movie?

Comment: Any additional information that may help tzo identify it? When did you watch it? What time was it likely from? What country was it likely from? ...

Comment: It was a german movie, I think it was made after 2000

Comment: For the future remember to add such things into the question, to facilitate identification as best as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may be [Sophie Scholl - The Final Days](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0426578/) which is about a group of students forming the resistance group *The White Rose* and their arrest, trial and following execution (I think even through decapitation). See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Scholl_%E2%80%93_Die_letzten_Tage) for further plot details. Considering the additional information from your comment, it seems like a likely fit, given that it's a German movie from 2005.